# Microsoft's Ad Mediator bug, UI hang on AdSDKTimeout error. How should we handle it?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, ads

I tried to integrate the microsft ad mediation solution in my windows phone 8.1 XAML app. The logic behavior of the control should be, if the first ad sdk doesn't respond within the time limit, the control try the next ad sdk.

But in my case, when an AdSDKTimeout error happens, the user get stuck in the current page. The UI respond (animations on click etc..), but all the buttons doesn't work. And this "hang" lasts since the next ad sdk response (sometimes it can take several seconds).

Is this a normal behavior ? Did someone already have the same problem ? How did you handle it ?